# Right way to reflect already pushed changes to local branch

Tags: git

Suppose I have two git branches `develop` and `feature`.

The feature branch is branched out of the develop.

When changes are made, those are rebased onto the `develop` and eventually pushed to the remote.

When some developer pushed his/her changes to the remote(develop) just right before pushing my locally rebased develop branch to the remote, what is the right(recommended) way to reflect the already pushed changes to my local branch and then push?

e.g. 
 1. Check out `develop` to local
 2. Create branch `feature` and make two commits `commit-C` and `commit-D`
 3. Rebase the commits onto `develop` and just about to push to the remote

```
 develop(remote)  commit-A -> commit-B -> commit-X
 develop(local)  commit-A -> commit-B -> commit-C -> commit-D
 feature(local)  commit-A -> commit-B -> commit-C -> commit-D
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your push would fail because commit-X prevents fast-forward on the remote develop branch. So there is no risk in overwriting commits on the remote (unless you use `-f` or `--force`)

If the push fails, you can simply rebase again:

```
git rebase origin/develop
```

or if your local branch is also develop:

```
git pull --rebase
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you are looking for, you want to get to a state that looks like this:

```
develop(local)  commit-A -> commit-B -> Commit-X -> commit-C -> commit-D
```

You should be able to use `git pull --rebase` when on the local `develop` to achieve this.